# How to test an Ambari custom stack installation?

Tags: hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

I want Ambari to manage (install, start, stop, status) a custom service. I've already figured out how the Ambari stack works, but I am now facing a dev workflow question: what is the best way to test it?

What I am doing so far is write some Python code (/var/lib/ambari/resources/stacks/HDP/2.3/MY_SERVICE/package/...), and every time I want to test it, I need to:

- remove the service (using the API)
- restart Ambari
- install the service (through all the steps in the UI)
- catch the logs

This is very time-consuming, and not really an optimized dev workflow...

Is there a better way to test the Python-code used to manage the service  (install(), start(), status() methods) ?

Comment: I'd also be interested in knowing if there is an easier way to test a custom service. I took the same steps as you did in order to test. I was unable to find a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

Although the question was asked a while ago, I've been run into the same problem and found a way to resolve this:

- set the python path on the command line: `export PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/`
- Run the script via `python ./package/scripts/service.py INSTALL /var/lib/ambari-agent/data/command-53.json /var/lib/ambari-server/resources/stacks/HDP/2.5/services/TESTSERVICE /tmp/out.txt DEBUG /tmp`

You'll get some help for the command line parameters if you just call `python ./package/scripts/service.py` without any parameters. The json file comes from a previous service installation over the Web-GUI.

You will also have to change the python path according to your OS environment. In the specified python directory (/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/) you should see links to the ambari python libs.